# How Can I exemplify spectrum multiplexing (FDM/TDM)

Tags: python, network-programming, signals, multiplexing

I'm leading a lecture on mobile networks this week and would like to have some kind of code implementation that utilizes spectrum multiplexing in some way. This is tricky to research as spectrum is on the physical layer, so I thought I would ask for some advice.

I've found some audio manipulating examples that supposedly use FDM, does this seem like a good example?

http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/f2010/handouts/labs/lab7/lab7.shtml

Comment: Hmm, unless your demonstration can show different loss characteristics due to your medium, I think this will be hard to do on an application layer for the reason you described. I'm wondering if the networking Stack Exchange site would be able to help you better.

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll post this question there as well.